# Properly dismiss keyboard in swift for collectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard, uicollectionview

I'm creating a simple messenger chat window, and i'm using `UICollectionView` for my bubble-messages. 
Now I want to setup the keyboard to show and hide properly. 
I used `NSNotifications` and created functions for `keyboardWillShow:` and `keyboardWillHide:` events. Also I setup `keyboardDismissMode` to Interactive for my `CollectionView`. 
So now, when I scroll up, and my keyboard is hiding (which caused by Interactive dismiss mode), i also got `keyboardWillHid`e event, which resets my UIEdgeInsets. So basically after I scroll up and my keyboard is hidden my `scrollView` immediately goes to the bottom.  My goal is to make it work like in iMessage.app, WhatsApp and etc. I will appreciate any help or advice!

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
   var customView: CustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       customView = CustomView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 40.0))
       customView.textView!.delegate = self
       collectionView.scrollToBottom(true)
       collectionView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

    }

   override var inputAccessoryView: UIView! {
       get {
           if customView == nil {
               customView = CustomView()
           }
           return customView
          }
       }

   override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
      return true
   }

   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo ?? [:]
        let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
        let adjustmentHeight = (CGRectGetHeight(keyboardFrame) + CGRectGetHeight(customView.frame) )
        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets
        if UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation) {
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, adjustmentHeight, 0)
        } else {
            contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardFrame.width, 0)
        }
        collectionView.contentInset = contentInset
        collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset
        collectionView.scrollToBottom(true)
  }

   func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
       collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
       collectionView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
   }



}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your collectionView is scrolling to the bottom when you interactively dismiss the keyboard not because the UIEdgeInsets are being reset to zero but rather because in this configuration the keyboardWillShow method is being called again when you dismiss the keyboard interactively.  Presumably because of the inputAccessoryView. To verify this put a println in your keyboardWillShow method and try it again.  I wanted to say this as a comment rather than an answer but I only have 47 rep and need 50 to comment.  But I think this information can be useful to you.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right. When my app starts, and my keyboard is hidden, keyboardWillShow s called, also when i dismiss the keyboard. Maybe i should use another method, like keyboardDidShow ?

Comment: i suspect it has to do with the inputAccessoryView being reintroduced after the keyboard hidden and thus the call.  you may want to rethink how the inputAccessoryView is presented.  Also the initial call when your app is started is because the inputAccessoryView is being added and thus the keyboard modified.

Comment: well, i moved code, which make insets to textFieldDidBeginEditing, and it's working much better :)